# How to change color of arrow of expandableListView?

Tags: android, colors, styles, expandablelistview

How to change the color of the drop-down arrow of an expandable `ListView`?

It would be better to just change color with, so animation isn't lost.

Comment: Make your own style/theme.

Comment: But I don't know which tag change this color

Comment: You can use the icons from an older theme (I assume you know where to take the android graphic resources) and copy them to your drawable folders. You can also elaborate them in a Graphic Editor (Gimp, Photoshop, Paint.NET, ...). Nothing complicate.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: I have alredy used icons but it display not good

Comment: Then re-read my above comment - if you **properly** use Android's icons, the results will be great. If not, then I guess you are confused about supporting **different densities**.

Comment: I can't take this images - I don't know where they placed

Comment: In Windows, they are in `Drive_Letter:\Your_IDE_Install_Path\sdk\platforms\android-*\data\res` where * is the API Level number.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, i try it. Now i juse need to edit this images)
http://postimg.org/image/675bdl1s9/

Comment: These look like **malformed 9 patches**. Please ensure that the extension is **.9.png**, not **.png**

Comment: Yeah! It helped me! Thank you man!)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately everything I've seen says that you need to use a custom drawable, like so

```
<ExpandableListView 
    android:id="@+id/expandableList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:groupIndicator="@drawable/custom_expandable" />
```

Then in `custom_expandable.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_arrow" 
        android:state_empty="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_arrow" 
        android:state_expanded="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I use it, but it's display not good. Like in this picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HU0J8.png

Comment: Try giving the TextView a margin on the right: `android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingRight" `

Comment: I tried it, but take this(
http://postimg.org/image/genbdwq0l/

Comment: I'm confused. In the first image, they were on the right side, now they are on the left. What are you trying to achieve? Do you still want to change the color? Or are you concerned that they look pixelated?

Comment: Sory) First image it's example from internet(i take the same issue). Second image is mine.
I want change color without drawable resources or create this resource fine

Comment: To achieve this, you need to make your own images. You can use a tool like this to easily resize them to support multiple screen sizes: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example

Comment: I used icons from this place: https://www.google.com/design/icons/
There all standart sizes. But I will try use other sizes

Comment: Did you put each image in it's respective drawable folder? (eg: drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi)

Comment: Yes, I did, but u saw result

Comment: its late but for anyone like me who used this ans, put icon in a layer-list to stop them from pixlating like this-->

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <size android:width="@dimen/value_24dp"
                android:height="@dimen/value_24dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_expandable_arrow_down"
        android:height="@dimen/value_18dp"
        android:width="@dimen/value_18dp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</layer-list>